# Roman numerals isomorphic conversion in Go

Tags: beginner, go, roman-numerals

I always try to port the roman numeral conversion algorithm to learn new languages. Reading the Go manual as a beginner, this is the most idiomatic way I've been able to write it.

I would love it if you could give me comments/advice on the following code, and also maybe on some questions I have regarding it:

- About the `found := false` flag, is there a better way of doing this? And by that I mean: breaking from a loop while storing a value? Because I cannot assign the variable `matchingGlyph` to `nil` to display *not-found-ness*, the only way I could think of was to have a separate flag.
- At what spots am I under-doing it or over-doing it?
- How does it look from a modern Go perspective?
- How is my error management?

What I know could be improved, but chose not to implement: roman glyphs order validation. Right now the code implements error handling for invalid glyphs, but doesn't handle invalid ordering like `XIVMM` (in lieu of `MMXIV`). Both would produce `2014`, but the ordering of the former is invalid.

Thank you!

**roman.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// RomanGlyph contains a roman numeral and its base 10 integer equivalent
type RomanGlyph struct {
    numeral string
    value   int
}

// RomanGlyphsByNumeral is a dictionary of roman numeral glyphs to their base 10 integer equivalents
// Ordered for efficient matching in RomanNumberToInt
var RomanGlyphsByNumeral = []RomanGlyph{
    {"CM", 900}, {"M", 1000}, {"CD", 400}, {"D", 500},
    {"XC", 90}, {"C", 100}, {"XL", 40}, {"L", 50},
    {"IX", 9}, {"X", 10}, {"IV", 4}, {"V", 5},
    {"I", 1},
}

// RomanGlyphsByValue is a dictionary of roman numeral glyphs to their base 10 integer equivalents
// Ordered for efficient matching in IntToRomanNumber
var RomanGlyphsByValue = []RomanGlyph{
    {"M", 1000}, {"CM", 900}, {"D", 500}, {"CD", 400},
    {"C", 100}, {"XC", 90}, {"L", 50}, {"XL", 40},
    {"X", 10}, {"IX", 9}, {"V", 5}, {"IV", 4},
    {"I", 1},
}

// RomanNumberToInt converts a roman number to its base 10 integer equivalent
func RomanNumberToInt(romanNumber string) (result int, err error) {
    count := len(romanNumber)
    runes := []rune(romanNumber)

    i := 0
    for i < count {
        substring := string(runes[i:count])

        found := false
        var matchingGlyph RomanGlyph

        for _, glyph := range RomanGlyphsByNumeral {
            if strings.HasPrefix(substring, glyph.numeral) {
                found = true
                matchingGlyph = glyph
                break
            }
        }

        if !found {
            return 0, fmt.Errorf("Cannot find valid roman numeral at %v", substring)
        }

        result += matchingGlyph.value
        i += len(matchingGlyph.numeral)
    }

    return result, nil
}

// IntToRomanNumber converts a base 10 integer to its roman number equivalent
func IntToRomanNumber(number int) (result string, err error) {
    if number < 1 {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Integer argument `number` should be greater than 1. Received %v", number)
    }

    for _, romanGlyph := range RomanGlyphsByValue {
        for number >= romanGlyph.value {
            result += romanGlyph.numeral
            number -= romanGlyph.value
        }
    }

    return result, nil
}
```

**roman_test.go**

````golang
package main

import "testing"

var samples = []struct {
    value   int
    numeral string
}{
    {2014, "MMXIV"},
    {1993, "MCMXCIII"},
    {1111, "MCXI"},
    {444, "CDXLIV"},
}

func TestRoman(t *testing.T) {
    // Test failure for converting integer 0 to a roman numeral
    _, zeroErr := IntToRomanNumber(0)
    if zeroErr == nil {
        t.Error("Converting int 0 to roman should have failed")
    }

    // Test failure for converting invalid roman numerals to int
    _, invalidNumeralErr := RomanNumberToInt("XAV")
    if invalidNumeralErr == nil {
        t.Error("Converting roman 'XAV' to int should have failed because A is not a valid roman numeral")
    }

    // Test samples
    for _, sample := range samples {
        result, err := IntToRomanNumber(sample.value)

        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("Sample int %v should have produced numeral %v. Failed with %v", sample.value, sample.numeral, err)
        } else if result != sample.numeral {
            t.Errorf("Sample int %v should have produced numeral %v. Got %v", sample.value, sample.numeral, result)
        }
    }

    // Test roundtrip conversion for numbers 1..2000
    for i := 1; i <= 2000; i++ {
        roman, err := IntToRomanNumber(i)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }

        backToI, err := RomanNumberToInt(roman)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }

        if i != backToI {
            t.Errorf("Number %v failed roundtrip: %v > %v > %v", i, i, roman, backToI)
        }
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is my error management?

[Error](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#error-strings) strings should not be capitalized (unless beginning with proper nouns or acronyms) or end with punctuation, since they are usually printed following other context. That is, use `fmt.Errorf("something bad")` not `fmt.Errorf("Something bad")`, so that `log.Printf("Reading %s: %v", filename, err)` formats without a spurious capital letter mid-message. This does not apply to logging, which is implicitly line-oriented and not combined inside other messages.

And see standard library `src/io/io.go` examples:

```
// ErrShortBuffer means that a read required a longer buffer than was provided.
var ErrShortBuffer = errors.New("short buffer")

// EOF is the error returned by Read when no more input is available.
// Functions should return EOF only to signal a graceful end of input.
// If the EOF occurs unexpectedly in a structured data stream,
// the appropriate error is either ErrUnexpectedEOF or some other error
// giving more detail.
var EOF = errors.New("EOF")
```

You don't need `found := false` flag, see 5, and for the final polished code see 8:

---

Code review:
1. Inside `func IntToRomanNumber(number int)`, the:

```
return "", fmt.Errorf("Integer argument `number` should be greater than 1. Received %v", number)
```

Should be greater than **zero**:

```
return "", fmt.Errorf("integer argument `number` should be greater than 0, received %v", number)
```

2. Using `strings.Builder` is a good habit.
3. Use `(string, error)` instead of `(result string, err error)` for function return values.
4. See standard library for sub-string `s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, glyph.numeral)`:

```
// TrimPrefix returns s without the provided leading prefix string.
// If s doesn't start with prefix, s is returned unchanged.
func TrimPrefix(s, prefix string) string {
    if HasPrefix(s, prefix) {
        return s[len(prefix):]
    }
    return s
}
```

5. About the `found := false` flag:

```
func RomanNumberToInt(s string) (int, error) {
    result := 0
ScanningGlyphs:
    for len(s) > 0 {
        for _, glyph := range RomanGlyphsByNumeral {
            if strings.HasPrefix(s, glyph.numeral) {
                s = s[len(glyph.numeral):] // s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, glyph.numeral)
                result += glyph.value
                continue ScanningGlyphs
            }
        }
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("cannot find valid roman numeral at %v", s)
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

6. [The Classic Roman Numeral Mistake](https://www.crosswordunclued.com/2010/06/roman-numerals.html):

   > On the face of it, IL and IC appear to follow the same subtractive principle as IV and IX, i.e. IL = L (50) - I (1) = 49.
   >   This is actually not valid.
   >   The subtractive principle for Roman numbers has these restrictions:
   >   You can only subtract a power of ten, and only from the next two higher "digits", where the digits are {I, V, X, L, C, D, M}.
   >   That is, only I, X and C can be subtracted, AND I can be subtracted only from V and X; X can be subtracted only from L and C; C can be subtracted only from D and M.
   >   By these rules, the Roman numerals IL for 49 and IC for 99 do not work.
   >   The correct representation for 49 is XLIX, for 99 is XCIX.

So the `RomanNumberToInt("IC")` should return error not 101:

```
// 0 value means invalid glyph.
var RomanGlyphsByNumeral = []RomanGlyph{
    {"IM", 0}, {"VM", 0}, {"XM", 0}, {"LM", 0}, {"CM", 900}, {"DM", 0}, {"M", 1000},
    {"ID", 0}, {"VD", 0}, {"XD", 0}, {"LD", 0}, {"CD", 400}, {"D", 500},
    {"IC", 0}, {"VC", 0}, {"XC", 90}, {"LC", 0}, {"C", 100},
    {"IL", 0}, {"VL", 0}, {"XL", 40}, {"L", 50},
    {"IX", 9}, {"VX", 0}, {"X", 10},
    {"IV", 4}, {"V", 5},
    {"I", 1},
}
func RomanNumberToInt(s string) (int, error) {
    result := 0
ScanningGlyphs:
    for len(s) > 0 {
        for _, glyph := range RomanGlyphsByNumeral {
            if strings.HasPrefix(s, glyph.numeral) {
                if glyph.value == 0 {
                    return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid roman glyph %q", glyph.numeral)
                }
                s = s[len(glyph.numeral):] // s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, glyph.numeral)
                result += glyph.value
                continue ScanningGlyphs
            }
        }
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("cannot find valid roman numeral at %v", s)
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

7. [In typography, a glyph is an elemental symbol within an agreed set of symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph), so naming the `RomanGlyph` struct:

```
type RomanGlyph struct {
    numeral string
    value   int
}
```

Is more readable this way:

```
// Roman struct contains a roman glyph and its base 10 integer equivalent.
type Roman struct {
    glyph string
    value int
}
```

---

8. If you are in the `main` you don't need to export (Capitalize) anything, otherwise only export intended items, and name the package `roman` then function name will be used as `roman.RomanGlyphToInt` by other packages, and that stutters; consider calling this `GlyphToInt`:

`roman/roman.go` file:

```
// Package roman implements simple functions to convert roman glyphs to and from int.
// See example.
package roman

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// roman struct contains a roman glyph and its base 10 integer equivalent.
type roman struct {
    glyph string
    value int
}

// romanGlyphs is a list of roman glyphs and their base 10 integer equivalents.
// Ordered for efficient matching in RomanGlyphToInt.
// 0 value means invalid glyph.
var romanGlyphs = []roman{
    {"IM", 0}, {"VM", 0}, {"XM", 0}, {"LM", 0}, {"CM", 900}, {"DM", 0}, {"M", 1000},
    {"ID", 0}, {"VD", 0}, {"XD", 0}, {"LD", 0}, {"CD", 400}, {"D", 500},
    {"IC", 0}, {"VC", 0}, {"XC", 90}, {"LC", 0}, {"C", 100},
    {"IL", 0}, {"VL", 0}, {"XL", 40}, {"L", 50},
    {"IX", 9}, {"VX", 0}, {"X", 10},
    {"IV", 4}, {"V", 5},
    {"I", 1},
}

// GlyphToInt returns an equivalent integer number in base 10 with error value.
// You can only subtract a power of ten, and only from the next two higher "digits",
// where the digits are {I, V, X, L, C, D, M}.
// only I, X and C can be subtracted, AND I can be subtracted only from V and X;
// X can be subtracted only from L and C; C can be subtracted only from D and M.
func GlyphToInt(s string) (int, error) {
    s = strings.ToUpper(s)
    result := 0
ScanningGlyphs:
    for len(s) > 0 {
        for _, glyph := range romanGlyphs {
            if strings.HasPrefix(s, glyph.glyph) {
                if glyph.value == 0 {
                    return 0, fmt.Errorf("invalid roman glyph %q", glyph.glyph)
                }
                s = s[len(glyph.glyph):] // s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, glyph.glyph)
                result += glyph.value
                continue ScanningGlyphs
            }
        }
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("cannot find valid roman glyph at %q", s)
    }
    return result, nil
}

// romanGlyphsByValue is a list of roman glyphs to their base 10 integer equivalents.
// Ordered for efficient matching in IntToGlyph.
var romanGlyphsByValue = []roman{
    {"M", 1000}, {"CM", 900}, {"D", 500}, {"CD", 400},
    {"C", 100}, {"XC", 90}, {"L", 50}, {"XL", 40},
    {"X", 10}, {"IX", 9}, {"V", 5}, {"IV", 4},
    {"I", 1},
}

// IntToGlyph converts a base 10 integer to its roman equivalent glyph.
func IntToGlyph(n int) (string, error) {
    if n <= 0 {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("integer number should be greater than 0, received %d", n)
    }
    var result strings.Builder
    for _, roman := range romanGlyphsByValue {
        for n >= roman.value {
            n -= roman.value
            result.WriteString(roman.glyph)
        }
    }
    // if n != 0 || result.Len() == 0 {
    //  panic("needs developer attention: romanGlyphsByValue list values must be > 1") // or test all values and remove this
    // }
    return result.String(), nil
}
```

`roman/roman_test.go` file:

```
package roman

import "testing"

var samples = []struct {
    value int
    glyph string
}{
    {2014, "MMXIV"},
    {1993, "MCMXCIII"},
    {1111, "MCXI"},
    {444, "CDXLIV"},
}

func TestRoman(t *testing.T) {
    // Test failure for converting integer 0 to a roman glyph
    _, zeroErr := IntToGlyph(0)
    if zeroErr == nil {
        t.Error("Converting int 0 to roman should have failed")
    }

    // Test failure for converting invalid roman glyphs to int
    _, invalidNumeralErr := GlyphToInt("XAV")
    if invalidNumeralErr == nil {
        t.Error("Converting roman 'XAV' to int should have failed because A is not a valid roman glyph")
    }

    // Test failure for converting invalid roman glyphs to int
    _, invalidNumeralErr = GlyphToInt("IC")
    if invalidNumeralErr == nil {
        t.Error("Converting roman 'IC' to int should have failed because A is not a valid roman glyph")
    }

    // Test samples
    for _, sample := range samples {
        result, err := IntToGlyph(sample.value)
        if err != nil {
            t.Errorf("Sample int %v should have produced glyph %v. Failed with %v", sample.value, sample.glyph, err)
        } else if result != sample.glyph {
            t.Errorf("Sample int %v should have produced glyph %v. Got %v", sample.value, sample.glyph, result)
        }
    }

    // Test roundtrip conversion for numbers 1..2000
    for i := 1; i <= 2000; i++ {
        roman, err := IntToGlyph(i)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        backToI, err := GlyphToInt(roman)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
        if i != backToI {
            t.Errorf("Number %v failed roundtrip: %v > %v > %v", i, i, roman, backToI)
        }
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
ok roman    0.038s  coverage: 100.0% of statements
Success: Tests passed.
```

9. Usage example (`example/main.go` file):

```
func main() {
    n, err := roman.GlyphToInt("CC")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(n) // 200

    s, err := roman.IntToGlyph(2020)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s) // MMXX
}
```

Comment: Additionally, [error strings should not be capitalized or end with punctuation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#error-strings).

Comment: In `IntToGlyph` it might also be better to remove the initial check for `n <= 0` and instead, after the loop check `if n != 0 || result.Len() == 0 { return "", errors.New("some failure message here") }`. Among other things it catches more failures (e.g. an algorithm or table error).

Comment: In `GlyphToInt` I'd make the first step be `s = strings.ToUpper(s)` to support arbitrarily cased input.

Comment: @DaveC: First and last comments applied, for the second comment putting `if n<= 0` at top is performance wise and lean, so I would keep it, then the option is to add another `if n != 0 || result.Len() == 0 { return "", errors.New("some failure message here") }` after the loop which makes coverage: below 100.0%, since coverage tests this problem so it is redundant. and makes coverage below 100.0%.  Thank you for the comment.